# What does cancellation policy mean Turkish Airlines fare rules page?

Tags: fares, turkish-airlines

I would like to purchase a roundtrip ticket from Turkey Airlines and am somewhat confused on the cancellation policy in fare rules [page](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/fare-rules/)

For international flights, under "economy promotion", it says that the rules for Cancellation/Refunds are

> Cancelations and refunds not permitted. Only taxes are refunded.

I get the no refunds parts but not sure about the no cancellation part. How does this even work? If I were to purchase a ticket with economy promotion and for whatever reason I won't we able to flight. And based on the rules, it means I can't cancel it, right? So, will I be charged a fee for not getting on the flight since I wasn't able to cancel it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many airlines allow cancellations and repurposing of the value of the ticket, but not a refund of that value, so you can apply the value to another ticket at a later date.

Turkish Airlines conditions as quoted does not allow this - you lose the entire value of the ticket, minus taxes which are refunded.

Comment: I get the no refund part. But I am still lost on the no cancellation part. If I can't cancel and won't fly, would I be charged a no-show fee of some kind?

Comment: @Bonobo123 no, the seat will be given to a standby passenger and you get nothing.  The airline cant force you to fly, and given they dont allow cancellations they cant charge you another fee for putting you in an impossible situation - there is no mention of a no-show fee in the T&Cs.